# Typescript Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

It seems between typescript 2.6.2 and 2.7.2 there has been a breaking change and the spread operator can no longer be used as it is in the code below.

Error: error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.

Anyone know how to resolve this.  My app still works but i get a compile error which i would like to resolve

```
 return this.col(ref, queryFn)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };  // This is the issue
        });
      });
```

Comment: Are you sure `a.payload.doc.data()` is returning an object?

Comment: Yes it does, i put a console log in after const data and it is returning an object

Comment: @ccocker: No; you need to check the compile-time type.

Comment: This is a compiler warning, *not* a runtime issue. What's the type of `actions`?

Comment: Yes it was data: T, so i changed it to const data: any and it now works fine - Thanks